# Why the output is the last line of data file test.txt?

Tags: python, loops

```
f_user = []
twitter_dict = {}
twitter_test = {}
fields="bid,uid,username"
a = fields.split(',')

with open('twitter_test.txt','r') as f:
    f_text = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(f_text)):
        f_text[i] = f_text[i].split(',')

        for j in range(len(a)):
            twitter_dict[a[j]] = f_text[i][j][1:-1]
        twitter_test[i] = twitter_dict

for i in range(len(twitter_test)):
    print twitter_test[i]['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(f_text)):
    ...
    twitter_test[i] = twitter_dict
```

Every single entry of `twitter_test` is a reference to the same dictionary, `twitter_dict`. Every position of the list is the same. It doesn't assign a *copy* of `twitter_dict`, which would make each entry different.

It's only natural, then, that a loop over `twitter_test` will print the same thing over and over.